# Unknown type name 'SCNetworkReachabilityRef'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Getting this error while building and running the project.

Unknown type name `'**SCNetworkReachabilityRef**'`
Unknown type name `'**SCNetworkReachabilityFlags**'`

I am using **Xcode 9.2** with **Swift 4.0**

I have installed following pods into my Project which uses **Cocoapod 1.6.0**.

1. GoogleMaps
2. CardIO
3. QuickBlox
4. QMServices
5. QMChatViewController
6. Quickblox-WebRTC
7. TTTAttributedLabel
8. SDWebImage
9. SVProgressHUD
10. SearchEmojiOnString
11. IAlertView+Blocks
12. Alamofire
13. SwiftyJSON
14. Fabric
15. Crashlytics
16. QMServices
17. QuCore-ThirdParty
18. SAMKeychain
19. FunkyObjC (version 1.3)
20. Firebase/Core
21. List item

I try to troubleshoot the error! But didn't get the proper solution!

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachabilityref?language=objc

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to figure out yourself

- Select `SCNetworkReachabilityFlags`.
- Press <kbd>⌘C</kbd> to copy the string.
- Press <kbd>⇧⌘0</kbd> (zero not o) to open the documentation.
- Press <kbd>⌘V</kbd> to paste `SCNetworkReachabilityFlags` into the search field.

You will see

[image]

On the right side there is the enclosing framework. `SCNetworkReachabilityFlags` belongs to `SystemConfiguration`

You have to `@import` a framework to be able to access its types.

So add

```
@import SystemConfiguration
```

in the file where the `Reachability` API is used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `SystemConfiguration`.

Correspondingly Class names have been changed. You would get it as suggestion in Xcode.